# Send SMS then email

Tags: java, android, email, sms

I'm currently developping an application in which I can send SMS and email.
No big deal, that's quite easy to do. 
Here is how I send the SMS:

```
private void sendSms() {
    Log.i("", "SEND SMS");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
            Uri.parse("sms:123456789"));
    intent.putExtra("sms_body", "My message");
    startActivity( intent );
}
```

Here is my code to send an email:

```
private void sendEmail() {
    Log.i("", "SEND");
    Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "address@fuu.com");
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My body email");
    email.setType("message/rfc822");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Send an email:"));
}
```

Independently, those work great.

But I want to send my email once my SMS is sent or canceled. 
I can't find how I can get back the close event of the `SMS intent/activity` to send the email.
Any idea ?

Comment: You may need to wait until one activity exited.

Comment: May you complete your answer ? I don't get what you mean.

Comment: If I guess right, than you call both functions after each other. You may need to wait for the exit of the first intent before you start the second one. I could imagine that you so will override the first intent on the activity stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) when starting this kind of activities.

You can then get the result of the started activity by implementing the [onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) method

The flow will be something like the following

> 1) startActivityForResult( SEND_SMS_INTENT, SEND_SMS_REQUEST_CODE ) where  SEND_SMS_REQUEST_CODE is a integer constant defined by you
>
> 2) The send sms activity finish ( either cancelled or done with it's job )
>
> 3) onActivityResult will be call on your host activity with SEND_SMS_REQUEST_CODE.
>
> 4) you can then do if( requestCode == SEND_SMS_REQUEST_CODE ) sendEmail();

You can do the same thing for the send email activity.

If you are interested on knowing what the child activity result was (ie: send sms cancelled or actually sent), you can use the onActivityResult resultCode parameter.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very simple. I was stuck in 'Event handling' like C# does. Thanks.